# Redirect stderr to second terminal / tty

Tags: terminal, shell, terminal.app, stdout

I've tried things like `rse` to differentiate standard-output and standard-error streams from a program; but I'd really like the option of viewing the two in *separate terminals*, without redirecting to a file and tailing it or something (let's assume that either one of the streams can print ANSI terminal-control codes.)

Is there any way to open an existing process's standard-error in a new Terminal, or something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open two terminals. In the second one, figure out its tty device by running the `tty` command. It'll print something like `/dev/pts/8`.

In the first one, run your app redirecting its stderr here, e.g. `myapp 2>/dev/pts/8`.

I use this so often for debugging that I set the terminal title to contain the tty number, so I don't even have to run the `tty` command. I do this in the shell prompt, combining the escape sequence that changes the title with bash's `\l` (that's a lowercase L) for the tty line number, i.e. `PS1=$'\\[\e]0;\l\a\\] ...'`

I often execute a `cat` in the second terminal before starting the actual app, just in case that I accidentally type something there it's harmless, and to make the cursor go to the first column. It's not mandatory though.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I'm using this by creating a new Terminal ‘profile’, with this as the ‘run command’: `clear; echo '(Append \` 2>'$(tty)'\` to a command in another window to view output here.)'; cat; exit`

Comment: For anybody else who might be running into the same thing, this doesn't work with Node.js, annoyingly enough: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4222

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct was "no", but then I came up with this ugliness:

```
sh -c 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2' 2> >(
    errs=$(cat)
    xterm -e "bash -c '
        cat <<\"END\"
$errs
END
        read -p DONE
    '"
)
```

Standard error is redirected to a process substitution where the content is collected and then passed to a script executed in an xterm.

I'm kinda proud that I came up with it, but mostly embarrassed.

Comment: But you're specifically running a command to receive the content in the second terminal, yes? That's not the same as directly writing output to the second terminal's tty, if I understand ttys correctly at all?

Comment: You might want to ask this on stackoverflow: you'll get more eyes on the question.

Comment: Flagged for a mod. First time I've had something moved *to* SO, instead of from. :P